# Faraday::Error::ResourceNotFound in Rails 4 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, faraday

My production server is getting an error when it submits a form. The logs say:

```
Faraday::Error::ResourceNotFound (NOT_FOUND: The requested resource does not exist)
```

Whole error here: http://pastebin.com/8YyWvC93

It's a tough one because it is only happening on my heroku server, but I can't get to the error locally because I can't get passed authentication of the clients API.

Recognise the error? Any tips as to where to look to fix it?